# Test Instances for Perfect Matchings in Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, examples, perfect-matchings

Are there any graphs with a known set of perfect matchings and other predefined properties, such as vertex connectivity, which can be used for testing the implementation of matching algorithms?

Algorithms for generating such kind of graphs, e.g. for generating random instances would also be considered as usable definitions of such instances.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at [this webpage of the LEMON software](https://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon/wiki/MinCostFlowData), which contains datasets as well as problem instance generators for min-cost flow problems (which you can use to generate instances of MWPM problems).

This [experimental survey](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10556788.2014.895828) (also linked from the abovecited webpage) also contains a lot of useful information, which will likely also help answer some of the questions that are implicit in this question (as well as perhaps some other MWPM questions that you posed).

Comment: great links! First I was bit disappointed that the experimental survey is not accessible for free, but then I saw, that a link to a freely available preliminary version is available on the webpage that is accessed via the first link.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that a free version of the survey is also linked in there; for the benefit of others reading this post, here's the link: https://www.cs.elte.hu/egres/tr/egres-13-04.pdf